# Mathematica does not replace \[ImaginaryI] inside Hold

Tags: replacement

Mathematica 10.1 does not replace I (i.e. \[ImaginaryI], the square root of -1) inside functions with the Hold attribute. Example:

```
In[1]:= Hold[I] /. I -> a
Out[1]= Hold[I]
```

I don't understand why this happens. I have not found any other symbols with the same behavior. If I create a new symbol with the same Attributes as I, it replaces without problem.

Why is it doing this, and is it the intended behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because sometimes `I` is not `I`...

```
Hold[I] // FullForm
I -> a // FullForm
```

Results in:

```
Hold[\[ImaginaryI]]
Rule[Complex[0, 1], a]
```

You can see that in the first expression `I` is held and remains the same.  However, in the second expression `I` is evaluated (since `Rule` does not have any `Attributes` to hold its arguments).  `I` gets evaluated into a `Complex` number; and since there is no instance of `Complex` inside the `Hold`, nothing is replaced.  You can get around this with `HoldPattern`:

```
Hold[I] /. HoldPattern[I] -> a
(* Hold[a] *)
```

Comment: Oops. I checked that I in Hold[I] was not changed but I forgot that I in rule might have been changed.